# Injecting values in enum based singleton

Tags: java, spring, singleton

I am using Spring 4.0.1 and  want to implement a singleton using enum. My singleton object needs server name which I have defined in properties file. How can I inject this value into singleton object?

There will be one singleton object for each server name.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have something like this

```
public enum ServerSingleton {
    INSTANCE;

    private String serverName;

    public String getServerName() {
        return serverName;
    }

    public void setServerName(String serverName) {
        this.serverName = serverName;
    }
}
```

You can set the `INSTANCE.serverName` field with the following bean definition

```
<bean class="com.spring.Example$ServerSingleton" factory-method="valueOf">
    <constructor-arg value="INSTANCE" />
    <property name="serverName" value="${serverName}"></property>
</bean>
```

Alternatively, within a Java `@Configuration` class

```
@Value("${serverName}")
private String serverName;

@Bean
public ServerSingleton serverSingleton() {
    ServerSingleton instance = ServerSingleton.INSTANCE;
    instance.setServerName(serverName);
    return instance;
}
```

**Note that I don't recommend doing this. Spring already provides a way to effectively have a singleton with the singleton scope.**

Comment: @amique I'm glad to hear it. The `enum` solution is nice but should only be used for truly constant elements IMO.